# Prove that $\int_\gamma z^n\,dz=0$ for any $\textit{closed}$ path $\gamma$ and integer $n\neq -1$

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that if $\gamma$ is a curve in the complex plane parameterized by a function $z(t)$ which is a continuously differentiable function from the interval $[a,b]$ into $\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ is analytic on an open set containing $tr(\gamma)$, then $w(t)=f(z(t))$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $w'(t)=f'(z(t))z'(t)$. Use this result to prove that $\int_\gamma z^n\,dz=0$ for any \textit{closed} path $\gamma$ and integer $n\neq -1$, assuming that $tr \gamma$ does not contain the origin if $n<0$.

**1st Try:** Suppose that $n\geq 0$, then $z^n$ is analytic everywhere. By Goursat's Lemma, the integral is $0$.  When $n<-1$, then $z^n$ is analytic everywhere except at the origin. But I am allowed to assume that $0\not\in tr\gamma$. So again the integral is $0$.

The problem is that I haven't use the assumption.

Note I am not allowed to use Cauchy's Integral Formula.

Comment: When you say that "[the function] $z^n$ is analytic everywhere except at the origin" and that, since $0$ is not on the path $\gamma$, "the integral is $0$", the first part is clear but how you draw the consequence that the integral is $0$ is unclear. Certainly there is no theorem stating that if $\gamma$ is a closed path and if $f$ is analytic on a neighborhood of $\gamma$ then $\oint_\gamma f(z)dz=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n\neq-1$, then $z^n$ has a primitive: $F(z)=\dfrac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}$. So,$$\int_\gamma z^n\,\mathrm dz=F\bigl(\gamma(b)\bigr)-F\bigl(\gamma(a)\bigr)=0,$$since $\gamma$ is a loop.

Comment: This is the uninteresting part.

Comment: @JoseCarlosSantos That's is what I was doing in the beginning but it seemed to easy. Thank you!